# how to save webpages to files with their addresses that has .aspx in it

Tags: python, asp.net, linux

I would like to save a web page to a file. The addresses are like

http://propaccess.traviscad.org/clientdb/Property.aspx?prop_id=487319

I tried wget and curl, and they say 'no matches found'.

What I am going with this is that I would like to write a python script like the following to save many similar pages.

```
foreach prop_id in range(400000, 410000):
    cmd = 'wget http://propaccess.traviscad.org/clientdb/Property.aspx?prop_id={} > {}.txt'.format(prop_id, prop_id)
    os.system(cmd)
```

Background:
 I need to parse the appraisals values to build a case for my property tax protest. Manually clicking things through to collect samples is just too time consuming!

Comment: Looks like the link doesn't work outside the browser I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library. First we should get session ID (it will be in a cookies after we visit the home page). Then we can download pages using these cookies (session id).

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()

#Get session cookies (session ID)
index_url = 'http://propaccess.traviscad.org/clientdb/?cid=1'
index_request = session.get(index_url)
session_cookies = index_request.cookies

#Download pages
for prop_id in range(400000, 410001):
    url = 'http://propaccess.traviscad.org/clientdb/Property.aspx?prop_id=%s' % prop_id
    r = session.get(url,cookies = session_cookies)
    print r.text #r.text contains page content
```

Page content will be in `r.text`.

Comment: Thanks! It seems I can do a lot with requests library.